# I could not log into Yahoo email for the past three days!

Tags: yahoo, yahoo-account

I can't get into Yahoo email and keep getting the same crap from Yahoo support: an engineering problem on the [East Coast](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/East_Coast_of_the_United_States) that should be fixed in 2-6 hours.

Meanwhile, three days have passed! The password has been reset 100 times, and I have been told it's not a problem on my end. I tried everything suggested here in a previous post, including `us.m.yahoo.com/p/mail`.

Is there any way I can access my mail?

Comment: Although the frustration is understood, the question could be phrased better.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using Yahoo's POP3 service with a mail application that supports POP3, such as Thunderbird or Outlook/Outlook Express/Windows Live Mail.

Here's yahoo support page on it: [link](http://help.yahoo.com/l/sg/yahoo/mail/classic/mailoptions/pop/index.html)

BTW, I have no problem logging into the Yahoo Mail inbox at login.yahoo.com, but I'm not at the "east coast" (of the USA I suppose).

Comment: If its an authentication problem, and not just with webmail, then POP3 might still fail, but it is worth a shot. Trying something will statistically provide better results than doing nothing. If it is an authentication problem and is only for the east coast servers, try a west coast proxy server to access yahoo, it might route you to a different server that might work.

Answer (score 0):

According to this [website](http://downrightnow.com/yahoomail) yahoo.mail was down earlier today but it is supposed to be working right now.